# Selenium with Firefox web driver can not find elements by Python code

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, classname

I can not find elements by using Firefox web driver, it print 0:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.unibet.ro/betting#filter/football")

 event = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-item KambiBC-event-item--type-match')
 print (len(event))
```

But it works when I change the web driver to Edge:`driver = webdriver.Edge()` , as i also have the edge web driver set up in my Path environments, printing the right amount of web elements

[image]

Comment: please put the relevant html code at here,  I can't find anything string related to 'KambiBC-event-item' in page source.  Did you give correct step to navigate to the issue page.

Comment: @yongi do not know how to copy the html code without copying everything inside those elements so i made a printcreen,

Comment: try driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.KambiBC-event-item')

Comment: i tried by className with selenium javascript client API, it worked fine. So i think the root cause is not from find_elements_by_class_name() , did you try add some sleep before call  driver.find_elements_by_class_name(), I noticed your website loading a little slowly.

Comment: @young actually the code is inside a loop so if it does not find anything the first time it will the second, what i read from the mozzila webpage is that i need selenium version 3.5 and up and firefox version  55 and up and my selenium version is 3.4.3, but when i try to upgrade it i get a message that i am up to date : `C:\Users\dariu>pip install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in c:\users\dariu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages`

Comment: There message means your local selenium stuff is alreay the latest ones.  you can navigate to folder:c:\users\dariu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib‌​\site-packages, or its sub folder, to see selenium-standalone-server.jar,  chromedriver.exe etc are latest or not.  but I still think the root cause not come from older version or selenium api.  as you said the find code in loop, it's not report can't find element in each iterator.  so at least the version and selenium api can workable.  I still think you not add wait for page loading before find element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the elements you're trying to find are defined with two classes (`KambiBC-event-item` and `KambiBC-event-item--type-match`).

I believe `driver.find_elements_by_class_name()` expects a single class name as an argument, and hence it's not working in your case.

You can try to use the `find_elements_by_xpath()` method instead as below (Pl replace the `//*` in the xpath with the appropriate element tag name):

`event = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='KambiBC-event-item KambiBC-event-item--type-match']")`

Comment: This is how the web element i is presented on the web site : `<li class="KambiBC-event-item KambiBC-event-item--type-match">`, i will try to use `find_elements_by_xpath()` but i won't switch to firefox  yet as long as something this simple will give me errors

Comment: This isn't an issue with FF. Your web element (<li>) has multiple class names in its 'class' attribute. Not sure how it works in Edge, but if you try to run your code on Chrome too, it won't work because of the same reason. (The exception thrown clears mentions that compound classes are not permitted - `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted`). I would suggest to use an alternate locator strategy (like xpath, css selector) if you want to find these elements by the mentioned attribute. HTH.